# Passing Dynamic jQuery variable between same-page functions

Tags: jquery

I've read several questions about using a variable in multiple functions by making it global (defining it outside of a funciton)... however, I have a function that produces a dynamic value on click (gets an href value of a link) -

I need to pass that resulting variable into another function.

Basically, I'm grabbing a clicked link's href value and then wanting to pass it to Ajax if a confirmation box is selected.

It doesn't seem that declaring the variable globally would work, as it's definition comes only if an onclick event is triggered.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the variable as a global with a value of `null`, and then set it in your first function. After you read the variable in your second function, set the value back to `null`.

Example:

```
var someGlobal = null;

function f1( ) {
    someGlobal = 'someValue';
}

function f2( ) {
    if( someGlobal == null ) {
        // the global isn't set! might want a message of some sort, or just ignore it
        return;
    }
    var myLocal = someGlobal;
    someGlobal = null;

    // do something with myLocal here
}
```

Comment: I like this method - and I've realized a second problem. I'm calling a return my_confirm() - which is a confirm box from onclick (inline) and getting the 'href' variable from a function that runs on click. However, the confirm() is running PRIOR to the onlcick - which is why it is access the global variable as NULL (given your strategy)... any way I can reverse the order that these functions are running? Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: The `confirm` is called prior to the `onclick`? The description in your question would imply that `confirm` is called FROM `onclick`. Could you edit your question and post some code?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. Now that I've got my global variable I'm not calling a function from onclick inline, but all from the click event associated with delClick - <a href="<?=$v;?>" class="delClick" onclick="return del_confirm()>delete</a>. You're answer gave me what I needed. Thanks!! Sorry for the run-around.

Answer (score 4):

Best way to achieve this is define the variable as you've read through outside sources outside of anything that is function(){}. What I usually do for my global variables for example is either set a default value or set it to a blank value above any of the other code I write in that JS.

Example:

```
var myHREFval;
$('a').click(function(){myHREFval = $(this).attr('href');});
```

Answer (score 2):

You pass it as a variable as your normally would:

```
$('...').click(function() {
       var myURL = $(this).attr('href')
       otherFunction(myURL)
})
```

Comment: this works if you only need to pass variable to function, but lets say you need to store the variable for later use where another function can access it after the other functions have run there course. Defining it outside of any functionality will allow you to in a sense store it while the page is open.

Comment: @Diodeus - my apologies. What extra data can/should I add to help? Thanks.